# Which anime episodes of Yu Yu Hakusho are based on which manga chapters?

Tags: yu-yu-hakusho

I like watching anime episodes based on which manga chapters I read. The wiki doesn't tell exactly which Yu Yu Hakusho episodes are based on which chapters and is also very incomplete?

Could someone tell me like they did with the Aria Manga?